how to make a ComponentResourceManager image to be automatic for each custom component in C#
I'm Trying to make a ComponentResourceManager image to be automatic for each custom component in C# from the decompile library .
so previously I had to create a library but the source code was stored on the hard disk that had been corrupted so I tried to decompile from the library but the problem was that the Resource image was not detected so it made an error so I posted a sample of how I made a ComponentResourceManager image automatic for each custom component
Please Guide
Thanks
code in testimage.Designer.cs
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Resources;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace testimagelibrary
{
    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    [DefaultEvent("Click")]
    [ProvideProperty("testimage", typeof(Control))]
    public class testimage : PictureBox
    {
        private int _Zoom = 10;

        private System.Drawing.Image _imgActive = null;

        private System.Drawing.Image _tmp = null;

        private IContainer components = null;


        public System.Drawing.Image ImageActive
        {
            get
            {
                return this._imgActive;
            }
            set
            {
                this._imgActive = value;
            }
        }

        public int Zoom
        {
            get
            {
                return this._Zoom;
            }
            set
            {
                this._Zoom = value;
            }
        }

        public testimage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if ((!disposing ? false : this.components != null))
            {
                this.components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
            ComponentResourceManager componentResourceManager = new ComponentResourceManager(typeof(testimage));
            ((ISupportInitialize)this).BeginInit();
            base.SuspendLayout();
            base.Image = (System.Drawing.Image)componentResourceManager.GetObject("this.Image");
            base.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(71, 71);
            base.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
            ((ISupportInitialize)this).EndInit();
            base.ResumeLayout(false);
        }
    }
}

Result code gif




It's quite difficult to understand what you're doing here: - why are you talking about a library that doesn't exist, when the problem is unrelated? - Why it appears this should be an Extender Provider, since you have the ProvideProperty attribute, but that attribute doesn't refer to a Property and nothing implements IExtenderProvider anyway? - You have Custom Control in the .Designer.cs file? What is that? - You show a .resx file that has no relation to the class it should belong to, but it actually doesn't. How can ComponentResourceManager.GetObject() find it? [more]

@Jimi , You have Custom Control in the .Designer.cs file  and You show a .resx file You show a .resx file that has no relation to the class it should belong to how can I make a relation because it comes from the library that I decompile please guide me from you

I have no idea what change I could suggest implementing. As mentioned, this code is a mess. It's not clear whether there was an IExtenderProvider that added a Property of Type Image that the extendees were using, and whether the source of these images was a satellite assembly used as storage, so the ComponentResourceManager was getting the Image assigned to the extendee using its name -- If you just want to get an Image from that resource file, you write, e.g., base.Image = testimage.ResourceManager.GetObject("[Resource Name]") as Image;.

This of course assumes that testimage.resx has an associated testimage.Designer.cs file, but it appears it doesn't, so the image you show is just the rendering of the data bytes, stored as a base64 string in the .resx file. The first thing you should do is rebuild the .resx file, so it's associated with a Designer. This makes it quite easier to handle

@Jimi ,  thanks for your response , If you just want to get an Image from that resource file, you write, e.g., base.Image = testimage.ResourceManager.GetObject("[Resource Name]") as Image;  for this I have an error  'ImageTest' does not contain a definition for 'ResourceManager'

@Jimi , The first thing you should do is rebuild the .resx file, so it's associated with a Designer. This makes it quite easier to handle for this what you mean is from Imagetest.resx then I do runcustomtool and then it popped up files Imagetest.Designer.cs . Please Guide me
